# How to get Qt widget type

Tags: python, qt, types

```
a = QtGui.QLineEdit()
```

Is there a way to query what Qt widget the variable `a` is?
It appears some Qt widgets would be supplied with `.uiType` attribute. But some (like layouts) are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the type of any object in Python using the [`type` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

```
print type(a)
```

You may also be interested in the [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__name__) and [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__) attributes, which will hold data corresponding to the widget's name and class:

```
type(a).__name__ # Returns class name as a string
a.__class__      # Same as type(a)
```

Note however that if you need to perform a *typecheck*, you should use [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
isinstance(a, type_to_test_for)
```

This will take into account inheritance.

Comment: Did you actually read any of the documentation you linked to? The `__name__` attribute is specific to classes, not instances, so `a.__name__` will raise an `AttributeError`. Also, `a.__class__` returns the same thing as `type(a)`, not a string. So to get the class name, you want `a.__class__.__name__`, or `type(a).__name__`.

Comment: Yes, I've read them.  I just forgot to remove the word "string" when I edited.  Also, I mentioned `__name__` in case he wants the name of the class object.  But I agree that is a little confusing since he has an instance in his code.  I've fixed it to do what you said instead.  Thanks for pointing out the errors. :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `a.metaObject().className()`?

See the [QObject](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#staticMetaObject-var) documentation for more info.

Comment: Although `staticMetaObject` will work, it's intended to be used with classes. For instances, there's `metaObject()`.